# Comment out HTML and PHP together

Tags: php, html

I have this code,

```
    <tr>
      <td><?php echo $entry_keyword; ?></td>
      <td><input type="text" name="keyword" value="<?php echo $keyword; ?>" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><?php echo $entry_sort_order; ?></td>
      <td><input name="sort_order" value="<?php echo $sort_order; ?>" size="1" /></td>
    </tr>
```

and I would love to comment both in one shot...but when I try

```
    <!-- <tr>
      <td><?php echo $entry_keyword; ?></td>
      <td><input type="text" name="keyword" value="<?php echo $keyword; ?>" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><?php echo $entry_sort_order; ?></td>
      <td><input name="sort_order" value="<?php echo $sort_order; ?>" size="1" /></td>
    </tr> -->
```

the page fails - it seems the PHP code is not being commented out... Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 213, accepted):

Instead of using HTML comments *(which have no effect on PHP code -- which will still be executed)*, you should use PHP comments:

```
<?php /*
<tr>
      <td><?php echo $entry_keyword; ?></td>
      <td><input type="text" name="keyword" value="<?php echo $keyword; ?>" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><?php echo $entry_sort_order; ?></td>
      <td><input name="sort_order" value="<?php echo $sort_order; ?>" size="1" /></td>
    </tr>
*/ ?>
```

With that, the PHP code inside the HTML will not be executed; and nothing *(not the HTML, not the PHP, not the result of its non-execution)* will be displayed.

Just one note: you cannot nest C-style [comments][1]... which means the comment will end at the first `*/` encountered.

Comment: This does add a little bit more (you need the PHP tags as well as the PHP comment markup), but this is the best way to do this, I agree.

Comment: But then when he uncomments he has to remove the <?php and ?> taags as well which is a little more work.

Comment: @flipper: so? it's an extra few characters v.s. having to rip out every block of PHP code by hand.

Comment: Interestingly, it seems that NetBeans 8.0.2 doesn't understand this (and so formats my code incorrectly even though this is a valid way to comment out HTML).

Comment: whats the shortcut to do it in sublime text editor? I know ctrl+c but that doesn't do PHP comments.

Comment: This ways seems quite unsafe, since there's a strong risk of it breaking out midway through because you used comments within the commented-out section.  I think it's better just to use an `if (false) {` block here.

Comment: I searched high and low for a solution to this issue and this was the only post I found that had a good answer!  THANK YOU!  Take my upvote ...

Answer (score 47):

I agree that Pascal's solution is the way to go, but for those saying that it adds an extra task to remove the comments, you can use the following comment style trick to simplify your life:

```
<?php /* ?>
<tr>
      <td><?php echo $entry_keyword; ?></td>
      <td><input type="text" name="keyword" value="<?php echo $keyword; ?>" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><?php echo $entry_sort_order; ?></td>
      <td><input name="sort_order" value="<?php echo $sort_order; ?>" size="1" /></td>
    </tr>
<?php // */ ?>
```

In order to stop the code block being commented out, simply change the opening comment to:

```
<?php //* ?>
```

Comment: Doesn't this solution result in two empty rows, each with two empty cells, still appearing in the HTML?

Comment: No, it doesn't. Try it and see! ;)

Comment: This is more elegant but has the same caveat as the accepted answer: that it is susceptible to breaking out if there are comments within the commented-out section.

Answer (score 16):

I found the following solution pretty effective if you need to comment a lot of nested HTML + PHP code.

Wrap all the content in this:

```
<?php
    if(false){
?>

Here goes your PHP + HTML code

<?php
    }
?>
```

Comment: This is the only solution that _actually works_, I don't understand why this isn't the top answer :) Thanks a lot, dude!

Comment: For the 3 people who actually mean this question the way it's asked: THIS ^ is your answer ;) - Note: I recommend the if(false): - endif; syntax, as it may be more obvious to the next dev that it is meant to affect the markup

Answer (score 4):

The `<!-- -->` is only for HTML commenting and the PHP will still run anyway...

Therefore the best thing I would do is also to comment out the PHP...

Answer (score 2):

You can only accomplish this with PHP comments.

```
 <!-- <tr>
      <td><?php //echo $entry_keyword; ?></td>
      <td><input type="text" name="keyword" value="<?php //echo $keyword; ?>" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><?php //echo $entry_sort_order; ?></td>
      <td><input name="sort_order" value="<?php //echo $sort_order; ?>" size="1" /></td>
    </tr> -->
```

The way that PHP and HTML works, it is not able to comment in one swoop unless you do:

```
<?php

/*

echo <<<ENDHTML
 <tr>
          <td>{$entry_keyword}</td>
          <td><input type="text" name="keyword" value="{echo $keyword}" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>{$entry_sort_order}</td>
          <td><input name="sort_order" value="{$sort_order}" size="1" /></td>
        </tr>
ENDHTML;

*/
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

PHP parser will search your entire code for `<?php` (or `<?` if short_open_tag = On), so HTML comment tags have no effect on PHP parser behavior & if you don't want to parse your PHP code, you have to use PHP commenting directives(`/* */` or `//`).

Answer (score 0):

You can also use this as a comment:

```
<?php
    /* get_sidebar(); */

?>
```